# How To Reject An Element From An Array?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I'm incorporating Highcharts into my Rails 3/Ruby 1.8.7 project, using Railscast episode 223 as a starting point.

I'm trying to chart a user's body weight over the previous four weeks.  There are some days when a user may not enter their weight and I want the chart to skip those dates.

I tried using the answer to this Stackoverflow question:

[Highcharts - Rails array includes empty date entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247344/highcharts-rails-array-includes-empty-date-entries)

but I'm having the same trouble mentioned by the OP in that weight values are being assigned to dates without entries. In short, a date without a weight is still being assigned to the array with the next weight value found.

Here's the code from my chart's series option:

```
  series: [{
      name: "Daily Weight",
      pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
      pointStart: <%= 4.weeks.ago.to_i * 1000 %>,
      data: <%= (4.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| Weight.weight_on(date, current_user.id).to_f}.reject(&:zero?).inspect %>
    }]
```

And here's weight_on function from the Weight model:

```
def self.weight_on(date, user_id)
  weight = Weight.find_by_entry_date_and_user_id(date, user_id)
  unless weight.nil?
    return weight.weight_entry
  end
end
```

It looks like what's happening is as the date/weight array is being built the date is being held until a weight value is returned. The date and the weight (which doesn't correspond to  the date in the array) are then added to the array before iterating to the next date.

How do I reject the date too?  If no weight value is found for that date, how do I skip that date, ensuring it does not get added to the array, and move on to the next date?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but a suggestion: instead of iterating dates in your app and querying database for each day, you should create a calendar table[1] and left join your data to it.

[1] http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would restructure the code use irregular intervals instead of expecting users to fill in values each day.

Produce pairs of datetime (as milliseconds) and values, i.e. an array for each point with a x and y value.

```
 new Highcharts.Chart({    
  chart: {
     renderTo: 'container',
     type: 'line'
  },

  xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime',
     maxZoom: 7 * 24 * 3600000, // one week

  },

  series: [

    {
  name: "Weight",
          data: [[1295954580000,3.9],[1297411200000,6.6],1298366040000,5.5],1318931520000,7.7],[1320143220000,2.2],[1320846960000,5.6],[1321356600000,2.1]]
    }
});
```

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it. I figured this out looking at the Highcharts irregular interval example. Your use of milliseconds makes producing the array dynamically much simpler. I just need to figure out how to use the dateTimeLabelFormats properly so the millisecond values are displayed as month, day, year. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't reject values from the array, leave them as `nil` (so they are later `null` in the JSON). Also, use `to_json`, not `inspect`:

```
<%= date_intervals.map { |date| Weight.weight_on(date, current_user.id) }.to_json %>
```

Some more refactors:

```
def self.weight_on(date, user_id)
  Weight.find_by_entry_date_and_user_id(date, user_id).try(:weight_entry)
end
```

But in any case you should be able to do that on the `User` object (which `has_many :weights`):

```
user.weight_on(date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the re-factoring suggestions. I'm now using the User object to get the relevant weight data.

Answer (score 0):

Change `self.weight_on` method to

```
def self.weight_on(date, user_id)
  weight = Weight.find_by_entry_date_and_user_id(date, user_id)
  if weight.nil?
    return 0.0
  else
    return weight.weight_entry
  end
end
```

Doing so will make those date that does not have weight data to `return 0.0` (float) which will be rejected by `.reject(&:zero?)`.  So only dates that have weight data will be shown.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I tried something like this but the problem is the dates are generated with the pointStart option. The generated array is just filled in against the first date, and so on. The correct way is shown in @Henrik 's answer below. Thanks!